# Почему приведение Родителя к Потомку выбрасывает ClassCastException?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, интерфейс, преобразование-типов

Для примера: у меня есть класс `Vector`, который обязан реализовывать все возможные операции над векторами — суммирование, умножение и так далее...

Особенность каждой операции в том, что возвращаемое значение из метода не `void`, а тоже `Vector`.

Например, сейчас у меня так:

```
protected Vector add(Vector vector) {        
    float[] dataHolder = new float[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size; i++) {
        dataHolder[i] = this.coordinates[i] + vector.coordinates[i];
    }

    return new Vector(dataHolder);
}
```

Далее, нужно сделать частные реализации вектора — двумерный или трёхмерный, с той особенностью, что в их конструкторе должен вызываться конструктор Родителя (`Vector`), и всё. Больше ничего, то есть: чтобы никакого дополнительного кода не было, но при этом сами операции оставались валидными для Наследника.

В этот момент при какой-либо операции в рантйаме вылетает *ClassCastException*.
Я понимаю, почему — класс `Vector` не обязан ожидать именно `Vector2`, или `Vector3`, но я требуют от него этого.

```
 Vector2 vector = new Vector2(new float[] {2,3});
 Vector2 spec = (Vector2) vector.multiply(new Vector2(new float[] {2,3}));
```

Тем не менее, как решить такую проблему?

Comment: потому что возвращается Vector, а вы его кастуете в Vector2

Comment: я понимаю это, выше отметил, что как бы "вру" jvm.
Но проблема всё равно должна же как-то решаться в рамках таких условий.

Comment: Вы либо можете превратить Vector в DimensionalVector, который сразу поддерживает несколько измерений, либо надо делать интерфейс и его имплементации. Все равно в джаве вы никак не сможете обойти вызов конструктора класса, который вы не знаете.

Comment: Спасибо большое, хотел бы узнать по поводу Интерфейсов. Если делать с их помощью, то какие классы должны реализовывать? Производные?

Могли бы вы более подробно объяснить подобный приём?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы реализовал через абстрактный класс и вынес бы туда весь дублирующий код. Выглядело бы это примерно, так:

```
public abstract class Vector<T extends Vector> {
    public final int size;
    protected final float[] coordinates;

    protected Vector(int size, float[] coordinates) {
        this.size = size;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    protected <V extends T> T add(V vector) { {
        float[] data = new float[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = this.coordinates[i] + vector.coordinates[i];
        }
        return getInstanceFor(data);
    }

    protected abstract T getInstanceFor(float[] data);
}

public class Vector2D extends Vector<Vector2D> {

    public Vector2D(float[] coordinates) {
        super(2, coordinates);
    }

    @Override
    protected Vector2D getInstanceFor(float[] data) {
        return new Vector2D(coordinates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вы не до конца понимаете свою же модель абстрагирования. Вектор в математическом смысле это *линейное пространство*, то есть определены некие операции, которые приводят к тем же векторам. Умножение и сложение векторов дает те же самые вектора. Поэтому когда вы задаете операцию умножения - вы и получаете вектор:

```
Vector resultVector;
resultVector=vector.multiply(anotherVector);
resultVector=vector.add(anotherVector);
```

Теперь вы решили озаботиться размерностью вектора, то есть количеством координат векторного пространства. В таком случае вы делаете так:

```
abstract class Vector {
   abstract Vector add(Vector anotherVector);
   abstract Vector multiply(Vector anotherVector);
}

class Vector2 extends Vector {
   @Override
   Vector2 add(Vector anotherVector) {}

   @Override
   Vector2 multiply(Vector anotherVector) {}
}

class Vector3 extends Vector2 {
   @Override
   Vector3 add(Vector anotherVector) {}

   @Override
   Vector3 multiply(Vector anotherVector) {}
}
```

Обратите внимание, что результатом выполнения операций сложения и умножения в классах `Vector2/3` является тот же самый класс `Vector2/3`.

Answer (score 0):

Общее решение для всех случаев вариативного поведения - выносите его в отдельный метод.

Заведите отдельный метод для создания экземпляра и перегружайте его в наследниках.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ примером, что бы пользователи лучше понимали суть решения. Спасибо :)

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с данным паттерном https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm
В метод в качестве параметров передается интерфейс. Затем можно подставлять все возможные реализации интерфейса.
Думаю, также данную проблему через generic можно решить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.